# PHP session subdomain + script

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, subdomain

I have a webpage with a subdomain, and I want to share the PHP session with the subdomain. I thought this was already done by setting the .htaccess of the main domain to:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".example.com"
php_value session.save_path /tmp
Header set Origin "https://sub.example.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
```

and in the subdomain's .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".example.com"
php_value session.save_path /tmp
Header set Origin "https://example.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://sub.example.com"
```

This seemed to work, I have access to the session on both the main domain and the subdomain. However, I need to run a script on the subdomain, that needs access to session variables and display its output on the main page. The script is called by AJAX. The session is not available to this PHP script. 
What do I do wrong here?

When I look at the session cookie in Chrome, it is set for the main domain, but there is no session cookie for the subdomain. Is this a problem?
There are lots of things I tried, but none worked... 
I start the session every time with:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start(); }
```

What I also noticed: session_id() on the main page returns the same id, but the script always gets a new one. This is obviously a problem. Does this mean that the request is not from the main domain and my browser id, but starts a new session on the server?

Comment: Why don't you save the session in the database?

Comment: Well, that is what I did in the end, but I still think a solution with session would be nicer.

Comment: You never know when you need more servers (docker) so this solution covers that.